# Force close app, when to get address ..NULL exception

Tags: android, geocoding

I'm trying to get a address with using this code by ihrupin from http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example

It works fine until I add geocode to get an address form latitude and longitude in `onLocationChanged`

Here is the code :

---

```
buttonGetLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
                try 
                {
                    gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                }
                try 
                {
                    network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                }

                // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled      

                if (gps_enabled) 
                {
                    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
                }
                if (network_enabled) 
                {
                    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
                }
            }
        });

        locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }



    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                // This needs to stop getting the location data and save the battery power.
                locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); 

                String londitude = "Londitude: " + location.getLongitude();
                String latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
                String altitiude = "Altitiude: " + location.getAltitude();
                String accuracy = "Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy();
                String time = "Time: " + location.getTime();

                //
                String address = "Adress : "+goToGeocoder(location.getLatitude().getLongitude());

                editTextShowLocation.setText(londitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n" + altitiude + "\n" + accuracy + "\n" + address);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } 
        }
Context context;
    public String goToGeocoder(String ll)
    {
        List<Address> almt;
        String alamat = null;
        double lat,lng;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        lat = Double.parseDouble(ll.substring(0,ll.indexOf(",")-1));
        lng = Double.parseDouble(ll.substring(ll.indexOf(",")+1));

        try
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            almt = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 5);
            if(almt.size()>0)
            {
                Address almtSkrng = almt.get(0);
                String admin_area = sb.append(almtSkrng.getAdminArea()).toString();
                if(almtSkrng.getAddressLine(0).equals(null) || almtSkrng.getAddressLine(0).equals(""))
                {
                    alamat = almtSkrng.getFeatureName();
                }
                alamat = almtSkrng.getAddressLine(0)+" "+almtSkrng.getAdminArea();
                //temp_koordinate.setAlamat(alamat);
            }
            else
            {
                alamat = "";
                //temp_koordinate.setAlamat(alamat);
            }
        }       
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            //
        }
        return alamat;
    }
```

The application was force closed.

Anyone can give the solution to fix this problem? 
Many thanks
kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer the reason for your Force Close without you providing logs that show the crash (i.e. stack trace)...

Without that information, the answer might be:

You need to handle the situation whereby geocoding returns null.

```
if(almt != null) {
    //do what you need to do
} else {
    //handle the null situation here
}
```

OR you could add a catch block to your try/catch statement to handle NullPointerException.

Comment: I try to guess whether this is in error because the geocode in thread and in implements of the location listener onLocationChanged
whether this effect if placed in locationonchange geocode?

Comment: i've adding :
 while(true)
 Log.e("ERROR LOG", localException.getMessage());

in Log cat :
02-24 08:23:24.840: W/dalvikvm(11770): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
and then FATAL Exception :MAIN

Comment: If your App is ForceClosing, the stacktrace should already be in logs (you don't need to add code to explicitly output it to logs). Please find the entire stack trace for the crash and add it to the information in your question.

Comment: there's no line "Caused by..." in logcat, so how i can to find the error log

Comment: You should be able to see the exception in red, it will start with the text you already posted in comment above, i.e. "thread exiting with uncaught exception...etc". The exception's stacktrace will cover multiple lines, that's why posting the first line hasn't helped me help you.